# Chart.js type error after migration v3 to v4

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chart.js

I'm upgrading my chart.js in my React project, it was working fine in v3.9.1 but in the v4.3.0 I'm getting the following error:

```
chart.js:5199 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'axis')
    at determineAxis (chart.js:5199:1)
    at eval (chart.js:5237:1)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at mergeScaleConfig (chart.js:5229:1)
    at initOptions (chart.js:5279:1)
    at initConfig (chart.js:5290:1)
    at new Config (chart.js:5312:1)
    at new Chart (chart.js:5593:1)
    at eval (ActivityChart.tsx:65:1)
    at invokePassiveEffectCreate (react-dom.development.js:23487:1)
```

I have no idea why this is happening in how to fix it.

My current code, that's working on v3.9.1

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const ctx = canvasRef.current.getContext('2d');

    if (chartRef.current) {
      chartRef.current.destroy();
    }
    chartRef.current = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Month 1',
            data: WLossData as any,
            backgroundColor: colors.GraphBlue,
          },
        ],
      },
      plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: isMobile,
        layout: {
          padding: {
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            top: isMobile ? 15 : 25,
            bottom: 0,
          },
        },
        scales: {
          title: {
            display: false,
          },
          x: {
            display: true,
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: intl.formatMessage({ id: messages.monthsInto.id }),
              font: {
                size: isMobile ? 10 : 13,
                family: 'GT-America-Standard-Regular',
              },
              color: colors.DarkSilver,
              padding: isMobile ? 5 : 20,
            },
            ticks: {
              display: true,
              // userCallback: function (item, index) {
              //   return null;
              // },
            },
            grid: {
              display: false,
              drawBorder: true,
            },
          },
          y: {
            title: {
              display: false,
            },
            beginAtZero: true,
            ticks: {
              display: false,

              callback: (item: number | string) =>
                // this only allows the first/base horizontal line
                item === 0 ? item : null,
            },
            grid: {
              display: true,
              drawBorder: false,
            },
          },
        },
        plugins: {
          // @ts-ignore
          datalabels: {
            display: true,
            align: 'center',
            anchor: 'center',
            color: '#ffffff',
            font: {
              weight: 'bold',
              size: 11,
            },
            labels: {
              value: {
                font: {
                  weight: 'bold',
                  family: 'GT-America-Standard-Medium',
                },
              },
            },
            formatter(value: number | string) {
              return `${value}%`;
            },
          },
          legend: {
            display: false,
          },
          tooltip: {
            ...baseTooltip,
            intersect: true,
            mode: 'nearest',
            callbacks: {
              title: () => null,
              label: (tooltipItem) => `${tooltipItem.parsed.y}%`,
            },
          },
        },
      },
    });
  });
```

I've tried to use different versions of chart.js v4.x, but all of them is showing the error that I mentioned.
Also I didn't find anything in the documentation that could help deal with this issue.

Comment: can you share some code, that causes the problem?

Comment: sure, just edited the post

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% percent sure why your code doesn't work, but tested it, if you remove the property `title` from the config-property `scales`, and the chart should render. The documentation also doesn't show a property `title` for the `scales` configuration.

Comment: Thank you so much! I couldn't image the problem was on title property. I found the documentation for this and now it's under plugins.
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/4.3.0/configuration/title.html